# How to Make the RequiredField Validator visible

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, requiredfieldvalidator

Using javascript or jquery, how can I make a Required Field Validator control (of ASP.NET) visible. If we check the viewsource of the Required Field valiator, we can see that the visibility is false initially. `$("#spanReqFieldValidator").show()`  / `fadeIn()` wont work.

Any thoughts ?

From googling, I understand that jQuery has some issues with visibility attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#spanReqFieldValidator").css("visibility","visible");
```

jQuery toggles the `display` attribute usually, visibility you need to toggle by setting the css.  You could spice it up a bit as well:

```
$("#spanReqFieldValidator")
  .css({ "visibility":"visible","display":"none"}).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call the `ValidatorValidate()` function in javascript to make a validator execute it's validation logic (and show up if necessary).  Something like this:

```
ValidatorValidate(document.getElementById('<%=MyValidator.ClientID%>'));
```

For more on the client-side validation API, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside).